# Is it possible to apply gradient colours to BG of Tkinter python widgets

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am just trying to add background colors as gradient colors! This may look my Tkinter-GUI  more attractive than common color codes. Is there any way to achieve this in python, can anyone please help me

Can it incorporate something like this?

```
bg="40%,#207cca 40%,#2989d8 50%"


def createwidgets(self):

        master_f = Tkinter.Frame (objMG.root, relief='sunken', bd=2,height =10,bg='#54596d')
        master_f.pack (side='top', fill='both', expand=1)

        self.Up_frame = Tkinter.Frame(master_f,relief='sunken',height=50,bg="#C0C0C0")
        self.Up_frame.pack(side='top',fill='x',expand='no')


        #self.Up_frame = Tkinter.Frame(master_f,relief='sunken',height=50,bg="40%,#207cca 40%,#2989d8 50%")
        #self.Up_frame.pack(side='top',fill='x',expand='no')
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't give most widgets a gradient background, but you can draw a gradient on a canvas and use the canvas instead of a frame as a container.

### Example

This example is a little bit compute-intensive, but it shows the general idea of drawing a gradient background. Optimizations are left as an exercise for the reader.

```
import Tkinter as tk      # py2
# import tkinter as tk    # py3

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        f1 = GradientFrame(self, borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")
        f2 = GradientFrame(self, "green", "blue", borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")
        f1.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        f2.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

class GradientFrame(tk.Canvas):
    '''A gradient frame which uses a canvas to draw the background'''
    def __init__(self, parent, color1="red", color2="black", **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)
        self._color1 = color1
        self._color2 = color2
        self.bind("<Configure>", self._draw_gradient)

    def _draw_gradient(self, event=None):
        '''Draw the gradient'''
        self.delete("gradient")
        width = self.winfo_width()
        height = self.winfo_height()
        limit = width
        (r1,g1,b1) = self.winfo_rgb(self._color1)
        (r2,g2,b2) = self.winfo_rgb(self._color2)
        r_ratio = float(r2-r1) / limit
        g_ratio = float(g2-g1) / limit
        b_ratio = float(b2-b1) / limit

        for i in range(limit):
            nr = int(r1 + (r_ratio * i))
            ng = int(g1 + (g_ratio * i))
            nb = int(b1 + (b_ratio * i))
            color = "#%4.4x%4.4x%4.4x" % (nr,ng,nb)
            self.create_line(i,0,i,height, tags=("gradient",), fill=color)
        self.lower("gradient")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @kakyo: "seems broken" is a bit vague.

Comment: @BryanOakley Using this method, I'm unable to render label text on the `Example` frame, I only see the gradient. Do you have any pointers? Is the label "under" the gradient? Using a standard `Frame` displays the text just fine.

Comment: Is there a way to apply gradient to a menu button?

Comment: Would there be a way to implement this onto a canvas rectangle?

Comment: @CoolCloud: no, a rectangle can only have a single color. However, you can certainly draw a rectangle by using a similar technique over any range of pixels you want in order to simulate a rectangle with a gradient.