# Creating Rounded Gradient Frames in Tkinter - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a rounded button that has a gradient in Tkinter with python 3, as shown below. [image: What I want the program to output]

I have managed to create a black polygon and the gradient separately, but I am unable to place the gradient in the polygon, as seen below.

[image: Current output of the program]

Can anyone Help my construct the code to make a button that looks like the orange frame above?
Cheers

```
from Tkinter import *

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        # f1 = GradientFrame(self, borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")
        f2 = GradientFrame(self, color1="#F7B17A", color2="#F176E4", radius=200, width=300, height=200)
        f2.place(x=299)
        #f2.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        
        # f2.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

class GradientFrame(Canvas):
    '''A gradient frame which uses a canvas to draw the background'''
    def __init__(self, parent, color1="black", color2="black", radius=0, width=10, height=10, x=1, y=1,  **kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)

        # Create Rounded Frame
        x1 = x
        x2 = width - x
        y1= y
        y2= height - y
        points = [x1+radius, y1,
              x1+radius, y1,
              x2-radius, y1,
              x2-radius, y1,
              x2, y1,
              x2, y1+radius,
              x2, y1+radius,
              x2, y2-radius,
              x2, y2-radius,
              x2, y2,
              x2-radius, y2,
              x2-radius, y2,
              x1+radius, y2,
              x1+radius, y2,
              x1, y2,
              x1, y2-radius,
              x1, y2-radius,
              x1, y1+radius,
              x1, y1+radius,
              x1, y1]

        self.create_polygon(points, **kwargs, smooth=True)

        # Set up drawing Gradient 
        self._color1 = color1
        self._color2 = color2
        self.bind("<Configure>", self._draw_gradient)
        
        

    # Draw the Gradient
    def _draw_gradient(self, event=None):
        self.delete("gradient")

        # Set Width, height and Limit
        width = self.winfo_width()
        height = self.winfo_height()
        limit = round(width * 1.7)

        # Set Colour Info
        (r1,g1,b1) = self.winfo_rgb(self._color1)
        (r2,g2,b2) = self.winfo_rgb(self._color2)
        r_ratio = float(r2-r1) / limit
        g_ratio = float(g2-g1) / limit
        b_ratio = float(b2-b1) / limit

        # Draw Gradient by lines
        for i in range(limit):
            nr = int(r1 + (r_ratio * i))
            ng = int(g1 + (g_ratio * i))
            nb = int(b1 + (b_ratio * i))
            color = "#%4.4x%4.4x%4.4x" % (nr,ng,nb)
            self.create_line(i,0,i-200,height, tags=("gradient",), fill=color)
        self.lower("gradient")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.geometry('975x580')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want to use the canvas for you would need to calculate all the colors and lines for. I recommend using an image for this case. First its much easier, second your canvas does not have to manage all of these items, last but not least its seems cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that but as I need to create several buttons with different sizes and colours that will change so, I will need to be able to call the buttons/frames

Comment: resizing is possible with `PIL` and you are still be able to `bind` an image to a command. How ever, as you wish to do so, be aware that your application will be slow with many of these buttons. In addition, you would create and delete lines of color by resizing. I think you overcomplicating things here.

Comment: As a [starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26182241/13629335)