# Is there an equivalent of a JPanel for Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need a equivalent of a Java Swing `JPanel` for my Python Tkinter application.  I need it to store a group of components that are seperate from the rest. How would I do this?

I couldn't find anything on this problem on the internet.

Comment: How is a JPanel different from a Frame? What features are you specifically looking for?

Comment: @BryanOakley I want to be able to have a separate layout manager (e.g. grid, not place), and to have a custom gradient background.

Comment: A frame lets you use a separate layout manager, though you'll need to use a canvas in order to draw a gradient background. In tkinter, any widget can be used as a container for other widgets.

Comment: See [Is it possible to apply gradient colours to BG of Tkinter python widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26178869/7432)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`ttk.frame`](https://tkdocs.com/pyref/ttk_frame.html). This lets use a different layout manager and helps separate components.